# How to implement parent child relationships in REST allowing hierarchies in JAXRS

Tags: mysql, rest, jersey, nested, hierarchy

## The Problem: How to retrieve a hierarchical object in REST?

I have a hierarchical structure of objects which are related in a parent child fashion. The data is stored in a relational database and each record is pointing to its parent by using a foreign key `parent_id`. In this scenario all records are stored within one table. Each hierarchy level can be resolved by traversing the list of parents until a root node is reached. How can I access such elements by using REST, especially when I may not know the depth of the hierarchy in advance?

```
+----------------------------------+----+-----------+
| Hierarchy Level                  | id | parent_id |
+----------------------------------+----+-----------+
| thing/sub1                       | 1  | NULL      |
| thing/sub1/subsub-A              | 2  | 1         |
| thing/sub1/subsub-A/subsubsub-A1 | 3  | 2         |
| thing/sub1/subsub-A/subsubsub-A2 | 4  | 2         |
| thing/sub1/subsub-B              | 5  | 1         |
| thing/sub2                       | 6  | NULL      |
| thing/sub2/subsub-A              | 7  | 6         |
| thing/sub2/subsub-C              | 8  | 6         |
+----------------------------------+----+-----------+
```

## The Goal: Resolve nested objects

Implement a REST interface which is able to resolve the following URL:

```
GET http://www.example.org/service/thing/sub1/subsub-A/subsubsub-A2
```

And the response is

```
{id=4}
```

## What was tried so far:

It is clear that the following structure can be easily resolved, because I know which path parameters to expect:

```
http://www.example.org/service/thing/sub1/
```

I am struggeling how to resolve nested sub-components within the URL. I did find the [sub-resource locator concept](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html), but I do not know to apply this to my scenario. I am using the Jersey framework for the implementation. I am looking for a way how I can traverse the REST URL from back to front, retrieving the parent ID at each intermediate subcomponent and thus being able to identify the complete object, for example like this:

```
http://www.example.org/service/1/2/4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Proposed Solution

In order to access the hierarchy of the path you can also use the path segments provided by the URL. This can be achieved by using the getPathSegments() Method from the [UriInfo object](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.18/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getPathSegments%28%29) you need to inject.

```
@Path("/segments")
public class PathSegments {
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;


    public PathSegments() {

    }

    @GET
    @Path("{ uri: (.+)?}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String resolve() {
        String hierarchy="";
        for (int i = 0; i < uriInfo.getPathSegments().size(); i++) {
            hierarchy+= "[" + i + "] " + uriInfo.getPathSegments().get(i);
            if(i<uriInfo.getPathSegments().size()-1){
                hierarchy+=" --> ";
            }

        }
    return hierarchy;
    }
}
```

This provides the following output:

```
[0] segments --> [1] a --> [2] b --> [3] c --> [4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be much faster to parse an URI structure something like this: `/service/tree/{id}` instead of using nested identifiers.

Creating links for the parents, siblings of a single node is actually very easy with [IANA link relations](http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml):

- `collection` - The target IRI points to a resource which represents the collection resource for the context IRI.
- `up` - Refers to a parent document in a hierarchy of documents.
- `self` - Conveys an identifier for the link's context.
- `first` - An IRI that refers to the furthest preceding resource in a series of resources.
- `previous` - Refers to the previous resource in an ordered series of resources. Synonym for "prev".
- `next` - Indicates that the link's context is a part of a series, and that the next in the series is the link target.
- `last` - An IRI that refers to the furthest following resource in a series of resources.

If you want an ordered tree, the [nested set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) would be a much better hierarchical model.

Comment: Thanks @inf3rno, I am aware that I could just parse the URL instead, but technically this does not answer my question.